# Is that secure if i used php if else condition for filtering users access outside the controller in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I working on Codeigniter Framework.
Which one is secure between two cases below and why ?

**Case 1** 
in my controller :

```
if ($this->session->userdata('role-users') == 'cs') {
 // redirect to menu_view.php that contains html for my menu
}
```

**OR**

**Case 2**

after stored session value into variable in my controller, like this one :

```
public function index() {       
 $data['role'] = $this->search_result['role-users'];
}
```

and then, i'm just do something like this directly inside menu_view.php :

```
if ($role == 'cs') {
  // some html tag like <li><a href="#">MENU</a></>
}
```

I'm just started to learn about programming. Hope somebody can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: it doesn't really matter. If you're going to access the session value multiple times, then store it before using it (saves you time writing).

Comment: Doesn't matter.

Comment: can you guys told me why?

Comment: You have to make new session controller and than check all condition on that for role.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a if condition in the Constructor, and you're good to go